# can't start Gnome System Monitor

Tags: debian, kde, gnome-system-monitor

I have Debian 10 & KDE Plasma. Sometimes when I double-click the icon in KDE to start Gnome System Monitor it appears to load and then immediately closes. When I try to start from the command line by entering

```
gnome-system-monitor
```

I get this:

```
(gnome-system-monitor:3146): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:21:17.441: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:127:35: The style property GtkButton:child-displacement-x is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(gnome-system-monitor:3146): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:21:17.441: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:128:35: The style property GtkButton:child-displacement-y is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(gnome-system-monitor:3146): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:21:17.441: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:129:34: The style property GtkCheckButton:indicator-size is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(gnome-system-monitor:3146): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:21:17.441: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:130:36: The style property GtkCheckMenuItem:indicator-size is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(gnome-system-monitor:3146): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:21:17.441: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:132:46: The style property GtkScrolledWindow:scrollbars-within-bevel is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(gnome-system-monitor:3146): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:21:17.442: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:135:30: The style property GtkExpander:expander-size is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(gnome-system-monitor:3146): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:21:17.442: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:142:29: The style property GtkStatusbar:shadow-type is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(gnome-system-monitor:3146): glibmm-CRITICAL **: 15:21:17.486: 
unhandled exception (type Glib::Error) in signal handler:
domain: g-io-error-quark
code  : 0
what  : Unable to find default local file monitor type
```

I'm not sure how it gets into this state where I can't start it, or how to fix it so it can start again. I tried:

```
sudo killall gnome-system-monitor
```

and get this:

```
gnome-system-monitor: no process found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by:

- right-click on the application in the Launcher
- click on Edit Application
- click the Application tab
- click Advanced Options
- click Run as a different user
- enter "root"

I can now start it again in KDE.

Comment: running `sudo gnome-system-monitor` did *not* work for me on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @HomeroEsmeraldo Did you get any errors when you ran that?

Comment: Yes. Check my question at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275959/gnome-system-monitor-does-not-launch-even-after-apt-installation

Comment: But basically I get the same as the last part of your stack trace. The glibmm error

Comment: @HomeroEsmeraldo Did you try my fix above? I think it got into a state where it was trying to run it under my user account instead of root, and it was just immediately crashing. My fix above always prompts me for a sudo account, and so far it's worked every time (fingers crossed).

Comment: I'm using gnome, I don't have the options you mentioned on your answer. But running as I did on the command line should be the same.

Comment: I imagine that Gnome must have something similar to KDE that will let you run an application as a specific user (with sudo access).